Django Admin panel css not align
enter image description hereDjango admin CSS is not working as expected.
As seen in the attached screenshot, the search box is misaligned. I need the search box to be properly aligned above the model data in the admin interface.
Steps I've already tried:
I have run collectstatic to make sure all static files are gathered.
I cleared the cache to ensure no old files were affecting the layout.
I verified that the custom CSS is correctly linked and applied, but the search box is still not aligning as needed.
Details:
Django version: 4.2.16
Issue: The search box appears out of alignment, and I want it to be positioned at the top, above the model data table.
I would appreciate guidance on how to adjust the CSS or admin template to fix the alignment issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
